# List View not showing name and presence

Tags: development, web-part, list-view

I am attempting to create a Visual Web Part to display users with presence (will be adding custom property to allow end users to choose which department's users they display)

However while I can retrieve and display data from the User Information List, it doesn't render as I might expect it to. Rather than showing the title (User's name/presence and hyperlink)  in a list format, it is just showing them as strings.

cs

```
SPWeb currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPListItemCollection listOfUsers = currentWeb.SiteUserInfoList.GetItems();
ListView1.DataSource = listOfUsers.GetDataTable();
ListView1.DataBind();
```

ascx

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Title" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Is it possible to get my ascx to show the user with presence? rather than as just a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate some html dynamically like this:

```
<span>     
<img class="PresenceImage" src="/_layouts/images/imnhdr.gif" onload="IMNRC('USEREMAIL')" name="imnmark" ShowOfflinePawn="1" id="IMID[GUID]" />     
</span>
```

Javascript function "IMNRC" do the magic

Greetings

Comment: Thank you, Marco. This helped me down the right path. 

I managed to get it working using some more spans, classes and the sip attribute.